# How to assign a value to the first n elements of a vector? c++

Tags: c++, vector, assign

How to assign a value to the first n elements of a vector?
Say, I want to assign 1 to a vector from index 0 to index 4.

I already have a vector with size 11. Now I want to put 1 to the first 5 elements.

Comment: `stf::fill(v.begin(), v.begin()+5, 1);` where `v` is your vector.

Comment: Or: `std::fill_n(v.begin(), 5, 1);`

Comment: Do you already have a vector? Is it big enough to put 5 things in?

Comment: I already have a vector with size 11. Now I want to put 1 to the first 5 elements.

Comment: Why not use a simple "for" loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

```
std::fill(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), 5), 1);
std::fill_n(v.begin(), 5, 1);
```

Note: `std::next` is C++11. In this case it can be replaced by `v.begin() + 5`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a vector filled like that, use the suitable constructor:

```
std::vector<int> v(5,1);
```

This creates 5 ints with value 1.

Comment: I already have a vector with size 11. Now I want to put 1 to the first 5 elements.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the original question. Other people's answer using fill work for that case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

According to the documentation:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
void fill(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        *first = value;
    }
 }
```

You can do:

```
 std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() +5, 1) ;//assume you fill 1 from index 0 to 4(included)
```