# OpenCV: In a matrix, how to assign same value to all elements in a row

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

For the following expressions in Matlab, **what is the OpenCV equivalent**?

```
A(2,:)=3;
```

From what I know, I can do it in OpenCV as follows:

```
Mat Arepeated;
repeat(value, 1, A.cols, Arepeated);
Arepeated.copyTo(A.row(1));
```

Here `value` is a 1x1 Mat with value 3. Is there a more efficient way than what I wrote above?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972966/how-to-assign-a-value-to-the-first-n-elements-of-a-vector-c) suggested about `std::fill` but the [examples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) show its usage only for a vector object. I'm not sure if it can be applied for Mat objects as well, or is there any other function. Can someone guide please on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
A.row(1).setTo(Scalar(value));
```

Comment: If I want to set multiple rows to zero, do I have to use a loop or is there a shorter way?

Comment: @Ruchir you can use: `A.rowRange(4,8).setTo(Scalar(value))`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. However, I just realize that in openCV, the endrow index is exclusive as opposed to Matlab. So, (4,8) means 4,5,6,7 only, not 8.